# Detectar Filas afectadas en un UpdateRange de LinQ

Tags: c#, linq

Buenas gente tengo un problema y no se como salir de el. Estoy mirando de realizar una barra de progreso mientras se están actualizando unos registro, como son muchos tarda lo suyo por eso la barra de progreso le ara la espera menos desagradable al usuario.

El codigo es el siguiente:

```
int indice = 0;
foreach(Objeto o in Listado){
    o.Calculo = (o.Superficie * o.Porcentaje)/100;
    index = index++;

    //Con esto lo mando al Cliente para el progreso de la barra con SignalR
    await _hubProgressBar.Clients.All.SendAsync("BarProgress", "Calculando:", index, parcela.Count);
}

foreach(Objeto o in Listado){
    _SaveObject.Update(o);
    index = index++;
    //Con esto lo mando al Cliente para el progreso de la barra con SignalR
    await _hubProgressBar.Clients.All.SendAsync("BarProgress", "Guardando en DB:", index, parcela.Count);
}
```

El primer bucle realizo un calculo, este bucle va rápido hayan 1k de registros como si hay 100k, en el segundo bucle cojo la Entity y le hago un update para que los actualice a la base de datos. Tal como lo tengo va uno a uno, entonces si tengo un listado de 100k de registros va muy lento porque el bucle es muy grande, pero con la función del **Hub** puedo saber porque index del listado va y puedo llenar la barra de progreso.

Ahora si hiciera un **UpdateRange(listado)** los actualizaría todos de golpe pero después no se como detectar el **index** para la barra de progreso.

Alguien sabría decirme si es posible poder detectar las filas que son afectadas con el **updateRange** o alguna otra manera para optimizar los **updates** ?

Comment: No me queda claro cual es tu problema, podrias explicarte mejor?

Comment: @Japv te la he modificado haber si la entiendes mejor la pregunta. Lo que me pasa es vasico tengo un listado de Entitys y tengo que actualizarlo en la base de datos, pero si hago un **Update** y el listado tiene muchos regitros se muere pero puedo controlar el porcentaje de la barra de progreso, pero si hago un updaterange para que los meta todos, no tengo index para controlar la barra de progreso.